# How to make cuke4duke find step definitions

Tags: maven, cucumber

I have configured cuke4duke and Cucumber with maven and written feature and step definition files.

My feature file is located at [ProjectDir]\features\example2.feature

```
Feature: Example of a feature file
  As some aspiring cuke4duke user
  I want an example of how it works
  So that I can easily setup my project to use it

  # This should pass
  Scenario: A simple passing scenario
    Given the letter 'A'
    When I check the letter
    Then the letter should be 'A'
```

My step definitions are located at [ProjectDir]\src\test\java\Example2Steps.java

```
package test.java;
import cuke4duke.annotation.I18n.EN.Given;
import cuke4duke.annotation.I18n.EN.Then;
import cuke4duke.annotation.I18n.EN.When;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

public class Example2Steps {
    private char theLetter;

    @Given("^the letter 'A'$")
    public void gimmeALetter(final char theLetter) {
        this.theLetter = theLetter;
    }

    @When("^I check the letter$")
    public void checkThem() {
        // just a stub
    }

    @Then("^the letter should be 'A'$")
    public void checkTheLetter(final char aLetter) {
        assertThat(theLetter, is(aLetter));
    }
}
```

When I run "mvn integration-test" at project dir in Windows command prompt it builds fine, but tells me that the scenario and steps are undefined.

Output:

```
[INFO] [cuke4duke:cucumber {execution: run-features}]
[INFO] Feature: Example of a feature file
[INFO]   As some aspiring cuke4duke user
[INFO]   I want an example of how it works
[INFO]   So that I can easily setup my project to use it
[INFO]
[INFO]   # This should pass
[INFO]   Scenario: A simple passing scenario # features\example2.feature:7
[INFO]     Given the letter 'A'              # features\example2.feature:8
[INFO]     When I check the letter           # features\example2.feature:9
[INFO]     Then the letter should be 'A'     # features\example2.feature:10
[INFO]
[INFO] 1 scenario (1 undefined)
[INFO] 3 steps (3 undefined)
[INFO] 0m0.053s
[INFO]
[INFO] You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:
[INFO]
[INFO] Given /^the letter 'A'$/ do
[INFO]   pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
[INFO] end
[INFO]
[INFO] When /^I check the letter$/ do
[INFO]   pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
[INFO] end
[INFO]
[INFO] Then /^the letter should be 'A'$/ do
[INFO]   pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
[INFO] end
[INFO]
[INFO] If you want snippets in a different programming language, just make sure a file
[INFO] with the appropriate file extension exists where cucumber looks for step definitions.
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As far as I can read anywhere, cuke4duke looks for step definitions at [ProjectDir]\src\test\java\, why can't it find my definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was wrong case in some of my Maven pom tags that caused the error. 
I cross-checked my pom and other project files with the following 
example project, and now it all works!

https://github.com/jamesladd/maven-cuke4duke-jump-start